# Trouble Creating a view in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, view

I'm trying to create a view to display the info I have in tables. The trouble I'm having is joining two tables and then displaying the data separately.

I have two tables: one is `tbl_videos` and the other is `tbl_categories_videos`. `tbl_videos` has two category fields, both of which are taken from `tbl_categories_videos`. the `category_id`s display properly in `tbl_videos` but when I create a view, I can't get the category name to display properly.

The closest I can get to it working is when both `category_1` and `category_2` display the same value in the view, but the should be different.

I've been staring at the screen for far too long now so i'm probably missing something simple.

Anyway, here's the SQL i have for the view:

```
CREATE VIEW `VIDEOS_view` AS 
SELECT `tbl_videos`.`videos_id` AS `videos_id`,
       `tbl_videos`.`date` AS `date`,
       `tbl_videos`.`author` AS `author`,
       `tbl_videos`.`photo_credit` AS `photo_credit`,
       `tbl_categories_videos`.`category_videos_name` AS `category_1`,
       `tbl_categories_videos`.`category_videos_name` AS `category_2`,
       `tbl_videos`.`thumb` AS `thumb`,
       `tbl_videos`.`image_1` AS `image_1`,
       `tbl_videos`.`video_embed` AS `video_embed`,
       `tbl_videos`.`title` AS `title`,
       `tbl_videos`.`sub_title` AS `sub_title`,
       `tbl_videos`.`section_1` AS `section_1`,
       `tbl_videos`.`section_2` AS `section_2`,
       `tbl_videos`.`embed` AS `embed`
FROM ((`tbl_videos` join `tbl_categories_videos` on (
    (`tbl_videos`.`category_id_1` AND 
      `tbl_videos`.`category_id_2` =`tbl_categories_videos`.`category_videos_id`
    ))))
```

any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: if you only need the category name of the category_id_1 and _2 why not just make a nested select? you can't join the second table on to different columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW `VIDEOS_view` AS 
SELECT `tbl_videos`.`videos_id` AS `videos_id`,
`tbl_videos`.`date` AS `date`,
`tbl_videos`.`author` AS `author`,
`tbl_videos`.`photo_credit` AS `photo_credit`,
(select category_videos_name from tbl_categories_videos where category_videos_id = tbl_videos.category_id_1) AS `category_1`,
(select category_videos_name from tbl_categories_videos where category_videos_id = tbl_videos.category_id_2) AS `category_2`,
`tbl_videos`.`thumb` AS `thumb`,
`tbl_videos`.`image_1` AS `image_1`,
`tbl_videos`.`video_embed` AS `video_embed`,
`tbl_videos`.`title` AS `title`,
`tbl_videos`.`sub_title` AS `sub_title`,
`tbl_videos`.`section_1` AS `section_1`,
`tbl_videos`.`section_2` AS `section_2`,
`tbl_videos`.`embed` AS `embed`
FROM `tbl_videos`
```

With this query you just select the name of the category from the second table through the existing foreign keys `tbl_videos.category_id_1` and `tbl_videos.category_id_2` with nested select statements. So for each `id` it looks up `tbl_category_videos` for the matching `category_videos_name`.

The problem with your query was that you can't join a table on two different columns because then mysql don't know on which `id` it has to join resulting in no join if the `id`s are different.

Comment: using the nested select rather than joining the tables worked.